# Checking a user registration form before sending

Tags: javascript, html, validation, node.js

I think this isn't right way. Maybe you can suggest something about error-displaying in error-container which fill in JS.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="display">
    <h1>Registration form</h1>
    <form>
        <div id="error-container"></div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="text-label" for="login">Login:</label></td>
                <td><input class="text" name="login" type="text" id="login"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="text-label" for="password">Password:</label></td>
                <td><input class="text" name="password" type="password" id="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="text-label" for="password2">Confirm password:</label></td>
                <td><input class="text" name="password2" type="password" id="password2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="text-label" for="email">Email:</label></td>
                <td><input class="text" name="email" type="text" id="email"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label class="text-label" for="tel">Phone number:</label></td>
                <td><input class="text" type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="380938866772"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input id="registration-button" class="send-button" type="submit" value="Registration"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
    </form>

</div>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**errorDisplay.js**

```
function ErrorDisplay(containerID) {
    this.container = document.getElementById(containerID);
    this.createDisplayingBlock();
    this.display = "none";
    this.setDisplaying(this.display);
}

ErrorDisplay.prototype.setContainerElement = function (element) {
    this.container = element;
};

ErrorDisplay.prototype.setDisplaying = function (value) {
    this.container.style.display = value;
};

ErrorDisplay.prototype.toggleDisplaying = function () {
    if (this.display == "none") {
        this.setDisplaying("");
    }
    else {
        this.setDisplaying("none");
    }
};

ErrorDisplay.prototype.createDisplayingBlock = function () {
    this.errorBlock = document.createElement('div');
    this.errorBlock.className = "error";
    this.container.appendChild(this.errorBlock);
};

ErrorDisplay.prototype.show = function (message) {
    this.errorBlock.innerHTML = message;
    this.setDisplaying("");
};

ErrorDisplay.prototype.hide = function () {
    this.setDisplaying("none");
};

ErrorDisplay.prototype.deleteBlock = function () {
    this.container.removeChild(this.errorBlock);
};



module.exports = ErrorDisplay;
```

**inputChecker.js**

```
function InputChecker(elem, minSize, maxSize) {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.elemTextValue = elem.value;
    this.minSize = minSize || 0;
    this.maxSize = maxSize || Infinity;
}

InputChecker.prototype.isLessMinLength = function(){
    return this.elemTextValue.length < this.minSize;
};

InputChecker.prototype.isBiggerMaxLength = function(){
    return this.elemTextValue.length > this.maxSize;
};

InputChecker.prototype.isMatch = function(reg) {
    var res = reg.test(this.elemTextValue);
    return res;
};

InputChecker.prototype.compareValuesWithElem = function(comparedElem) {
    this.comparedElem = comparedElem;
    return this.elemTextValue != this.comparedElem.value;
};

module.exports = InputChecker;
```

**formValidation.js**

```
var InputChecker = require('./InputChecker');
var ErrorDisplay = require('./ErrorDisplay');

function FormValidation() {
    this.err = new ErrorDisplay("error-container");
}

FormValidation.prototype.validate = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.checkLoginInput() && this.checkPasswordInput() && this.checkEmailInput()) {
        this.err.hide();
        alert("done");
    }

};

FormValidation.prototype.checkLoginInput = function () {
    var loginElement = document.getElementById("login");
    var reg = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,}(_?|-?){1}?[a-zA-Z]+(\d+)?$/i;
    var login = new InputChecker(loginElement, 3, 30);

    if (login.isLessMinLength()) {
        this.err.show("min");

        return false;
    }

    if (login.isBiggerMaxLength()) {
        this.err.show("max");
        return false;
    }

    if (reg && !login.isMatch(reg)) {
        this.err.show("format");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};

FormValidation.prototype.checkPasswordInput = function () {
    var passwordElement = document.getElementById("password");
    var confirmPasswordElement = document.getElementById("password2");
    var reg = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,}(_?|-?){1}?[a-zA-Z]+(\d+)?$/i;
    var passwordInput = new InputChecker(passwordElement, 3, 30);

    if (passwordInput.isLessMinLength()) {
        this.err.show("min");
        return false;
    }

    if (passwordInput.isBiggerMaxLength()) {
        this.err.show("max");
        return false;
    }

    if (reg && !passwordInput.isMatch(reg)) {
        this.err.show("format");
        return false;
    }

    if (passwordInput.compareValuesWithElem(confirmPasswordElement)) {
        this.err.show("password doesnt equals");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};


FormValidation.prototype.checkEmailInput = function () {
    var emailElement = document.getElementById("email");
    var reg = /(\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/i;
    var email = new InputChecker(emailElement, 3, 30);

    if (email.isLessMinLength()) {
        this.err.show("min");
        return false;
    }

    if (email.isBiggerMaxLength()) {
        this.err.show("max");
        return false;
    }

    if (reg && !email.isMatch(reg)) {
        this.err.show("format");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};


module.exports = FormValidation;
```

And the run js file **script.js**

```
var FormValidation = require("./FormValidation");

var registrationButton = document.getElementById("registration-button");
var validation = new FormValidation();

registrationButton.addEventListener("click", validation.validate.bind(validation));
```

Comment: I'd avoid any type of regex on a password, for one reason, it's very anti-user-friendly. Try not to be this guy: "Each bit of advice (*your regex*) may be useful against a specific threat, motivating security professionals to offer them in an attempt to cover their bases and avoid blame for any potential security breaches regardless of the inconvenience imposed on users. This approach is predicted to lead to failure" [Source](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/250408/passwordsAndImperfectAuth.pdf)